# What exactly is the startup.A51 code included in Keil IDE for 8051?

Tags: keil, 8051

When I create a new project in Keil uVision, it asks me regarding adding a startup code ie startup.A51. To which I click on NO

[image]

still, when I go to debug, I see it consumes 389 states. I am curious to know what does that 389 states contain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1296.htm :

- Clears DATA and optionally PDATA and XDATA memory
- Sets up the reentrant stacks (if necessary))
- Initializes C Global Variables (see INIT.A51)
- Sets the Stack Pointer (SP)
- Jumps to your MAIN C function